# Modal popup, update panel and client side update

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, c#-2.0, modalpopupextender

I am trying to display a modal pop up after updating pop up controls' values, all in client side.

A link button in a grid row is clicked. Using some of the data from that row, I call a javascript function to populate modal pop up's controls and show it. Modal pop up pops up fine but contorls are all blank. (removing UpdateMode="Consitional" has no effect).
I have removed all formatting lines to keep the code short.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlNewIDS" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="divReassign" Width="350" Style="border:solid 2px navy;display:none;background: url(../assets/images/bg3.gif);"> 
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFacilityCount" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCurrIDSName_BK" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCurrSiteName" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSOK" Text="OK" Width="75" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" Width="75" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" 
            ID="mpeNewIDS" 
            TargetControlID="btnFake" 
            BackgroundCssClass="backgrondModal" 
            DropShadow="true" 
            BehaviorID="mpeNewIDS"
            PopupControlID="divReassign" 
            CancelControlID="btnCancel"  />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFake" Style="display:none" />   
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is the row's template where the link is displayed:

```
<a id='a_<%# Eval("IDSID") %>' href="javascript:void(0);" 
    onclick="PopulateView('<%# Eval("idsid") %>', '<%# Eval("cnt" %>', '<%# Eval("idsname") %>', '<%# Eval("sitename") %>')">Reassign</a>
```

Javascript:
I traced the code and this function has all the correct parameter values.

```
function PopulateView(idsid, cnt, idsname, sitename) {
    lblCurrIDSName_BK = document.getElementById('<%=lblCurrIDSName_BK.ClientID %>');
    lblFacilityCount = document.getElementById('<%=lblFacilityCount.ClientID %>');
    lblCurrSiteName = document.getElementById('<%=lblCurrSiteName.ClientID %>');

    lblCurrIDSName_BK.value = idsname;
    lblCurrSiteName.value = sitename;
    lblFacilityCount.value = cnt;
    ShowNewIDSModalPopup();
}
function ShowNewIDSModalPopup() {
    $find("mpeNewIDS").show();
    return false;
}

function HideNewIDSModalPopup() {
    $find("mpeNewIDS").hide();
    return false;
}
```

When the link in grid's row is clicked, I call "PopulateView('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')", where a, b, c and d are from select columns of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your .aspx page. It will open popup when your linkbutton click event. 
configure link button like

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Verified Count">
  <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="verifycount" runat="server" OnClick="verifycount_Click"> <%# Eval("VerifiedCount")%> </asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

this is for your popup.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" style="display:none" />
 <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup_verifyInventory" runat="server"                   PopupControlID="verifyInventory_popup" TargetControlID="btn">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:panel runat="server"  ID="verifyInventory_popup" BorderStyle="solid"            BorderWidth="1px">
   <table width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" align="center">
       <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><strong> Verify Asset Details </strong></td>
            <td><asp:ImageButton id="close" TabIndex="1" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" ImageUrl="~/Images/remove.gif" Height="30" Width="30" ToolTip="Close"  OnClientClick="HidePopUp_verifyInventory()"/></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
             <asp:GridView ID="grdgrid" runat="server" 
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="true" Width="290px" >
             </asp:GridView>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</asp:panel>
```

and write link button click event in .aspx.cs page like

```
 protected void verifycount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //your code place here
      //it will show your popup  
      popup_verifyInventory.Show();
    }
```

write Javascript like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var ShowVerifyInventory = '<%=Your popup control ID %>';
         function ShowPopUp_verifyInventory() {
             $find(ShowVerifyInventory).show();
         }

         var HideVerifyInventory = '<%=Your popup control ID %>';
         function HidePopUp_verifyInventory() {
             $find(HideVerifyInventory).hide();
         }
</script>
```

the popup will bind the values in gridview.

Comment: I want to do this client side. My grid is not inside pop up. In response to a click on an <a href ..> that is on every row of the grid, I want to call a javascript function, pass it the some values from the selected row, and have the pop up open with those values assigned to labels inside pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on doing this client side and did on the server side, using RowDataBound of grid to add alink button and assigning the column values I needed to "Command Arguments" of linkbutton.